# Youtube scope for unity dash

Tags: unity, youtube, scopes

I just added the scope-youtube from the Lens for Unity ppa (atareao/lenses) along with the yavol needed lens to work with. I can open the yavol config tool to select browser/download/whatever, and the unity lens is there, letting me type and modify usual youtube filters but it retrieves no results. Of course, Ive logged out/back in and even rebooted but still no luck.

Has anyone had these issues? Im using Ubuntu 12.10 64b. Maybe its just a Youtube code update that broke the scope? If someone could check if it works for them Id be grateful.

Its a damn, this scope along with the Rottentomatoes and Piratebay are the best pair Ive ever meet for unity dash, and they are all out of Ubuntu official repos.